# Finding Google DataStore "not equal to empty string" correct query syntax

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I have a **Google App Engine** project that uses the **DataStore** for backend data hosting.

I am trying to create a simple query that queries on two properties, one of which is a "not equal" to empty string.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
query = Race.query(ndb.AND(Race.processing == True, Race.assignment_id != ''))
races = query.fetch(limit)
```

However, this does not respect the `!=`. I know from the docs that `!=` is essentially a combination of `>` and `<` operators, but I don't know how to apply that to an empty string.

Has someone tried this before? **How can I query on two properties, one of which is a "not equals empty string"?**:

- `Race.processing == True`
- `Race.assignment_id != ''`

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a legitimate question with minimal documentation out there about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried this via my remote API:

```
> x = User(first_name='test', last_name='')
> x.put()
Key('User', 5965989720096768)
> User.query(User.first_name=='test', User.last_name=='').count()
1
> User.query().count()
219L
> User.query(User.last_name!='').count()
218
> User.query(User.last_name=='').count()
1
```

Works as expected, double check your empty string is actually not a null value

Comment: Works like a charm. Looks like I was misunderstanding the use of the `AND` operator.